# Get end dates of months in previous quarter and get all the month end dates for previous year from a date column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to python and pyspark. I am working on a dataframe having dates in integer format. I have to find the max date from the column and based on that date i have to find -

1. last 12 month end dates.
2. previous quarter month end dates
3. last year month end dates.

This is the dataframe

| date |
| --- |
| 20201219 |
| 20201210 |
| 20201012 |
| 20200718 |
| 20200624 |

max_date(date) = 20201219

output dataframe -

| custom_date | info |
| --- | --- |
| 20200731 | prev quarter |
| 20200831 | prev quarter |
| 20200930 | prev quarter |
| 20201130 | current year |
| 20201031 | current year |
| 20200930 | current year |
| 20200831 | current year |
| 20200731 | current year |
| 20200630 | current year |
| 20200531 | current year |
| 20200430 | current year |
| 20200331 | current year |
| 20200229 | current year |
| 20200131 | current year |
| 20191231 | current year |
| 20191231 | prev year |
| 20191130 | prev year |
| 20191031 | prev year |
| 20190930 | prev year |
| 20190831 | prev year |
| 20190731 | prev year |
| 20190630 | prev year |
| 20190531 | prev year |
| 20190430 | prev year |
| 20190331 | prev year |
| 20190228 | prev year |
| 20190131 | prev year |

I have tried some cod so far and i am able to get current year but stuck in getting quarter and prev year

Answer (score 0):

You can construct some sequence of dates and explode them all:

```
maxdate = df.select(F.to_date(F.max('date'), 'yyyyMMdd').cast('string')).head()[0]

df2 = spark.sql(f"""
select explode(transform(sequence(trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'quarter') - interval 2 months, trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'quarter'), interval 1 month), x -> x - interval 1 day)) as custom_date, 'prev quarter' as info

union all

select explode(transform(sequence(trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'month'), trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'month') - interval 11 month, interval -1 month), x -> x - interval 1 day)) as custom_date, 'current year' as info

union all

select explode(transform(sequence(trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'year'), trunc(to_date('{maxdate}'), 'year') - interval 11 month, interval -1 month), x -> x - interval 1 day)) as custom_date, 'prev year' as info
""")

df2.show(99)
+-----------+------------+
|custom_date|        info|
+-----------+------------+
| 2020-07-31|prev quarter|
| 2020-08-31|prev quarter|
| 2020-09-30|prev quarter|
| 2020-11-30|current year|
| 2020-10-31|current year|
| 2020-09-30|current year|
| 2020-08-31|current year|
| 2020-07-31|current year|
| 2020-06-30|current year|
| 2020-05-31|current year|
| 2020-04-30|current year|
| 2020-03-31|current year|
| 2020-02-29|current year|
| 2020-01-31|current year|
| 2019-12-31|current year|
| 2019-12-31|   prev year|
| 2019-11-30|   prev year|
| 2019-10-31|   prev year|
| 2019-09-30|   prev year|
| 2019-08-31|   prev year|
| 2019-07-31|   prev year|
| 2019-06-30|   prev year|
| 2019-05-31|   prev year|
| 2019-04-30|   prev year|
| 2019-03-31|   prev year|
| 2019-02-28|   prev year|
| 2019-01-31|   prev year|
+-----------+------------+
```